# Responsive image hover caption

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

The problem I am facing is that the hover caption `.caption-text` and overlay `.blur` are fixed width and height whereas the image is responsive.

Any suggestions on how to modify this code to make the the overlay and caption fit the image width and height?

```css
.caption-style-4 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.caption-style-4 li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.caption-style-4 li:hover .caption {
  opacity: 1;
}
.caption-style-4 li:hover img {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.15, 1.15);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.15, 1.15);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.15, 1.15);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.15, 1.15);
  -o-transform: scale(1.15, 1.15);
}
.caption-style-4 img {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  float: left;
  z-index: 4;
}
.caption-style-4 .caption {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
}
.caption-style-4 img {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
.caption-style-4 .blur {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
}
.caption-style-4 .caption-text h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.caption-style-4 .caption-text {
  z-index: 10;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-a4">
  <ul class="caption-style-4">
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-600-480-1.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="caption">
        <div class="blur"></div>
        <div class="caption-text">
          <h1>Amazing Caption</h1>
          <p>Whatever It Is - Always Awesome</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul </div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GNzMNV

Comment: Please can you include your compiled HTML rather than the PHP to allow us to reproduce your issue. Having a scan through it's likely that this is due to your use of absolute positioning.

Comment: The source link is here: http://hasinhayder.github.io/ImageCaptionHoverAnimation/

Comment: I figured it was because of the absolute positions as there is no w/h to force the div open. Looking for a suggestions / tutorial link that could help me around this if possible

Comment: I should be able to assist but to do so I will need a reproducible example. Please amend your question and I'll see what I can do!

Comment: Just put a codepen in - does that help?

Comment: Thanks, although for future reference the code must be in the question itself as an external link can not always be relied on to be there. I have done this for you. Seems like you have some answers so no need for me anymore! I would suggest however, that you use the CSS only solution; Javascript/jQuery is not really necessary to get the result you are after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include jquery.js and calculate the width, height of the image.
Also add to css  `.singlePillar .caption {top:0px;}`
Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/hc2tr7s3/

Answer (score 1):

Just update your css

```
.caption-style-4 .caption-text {
    z-index: 10;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 95px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
.caption-style-4 .blur {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
}
.caption-style-4 .caption {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

here is the updated codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbLEXr

let me know if it still not working.